# Mono: The entry point method could not be loaded

Tags: executable, mono

When I'm trying to run some mono app I'm getting an error saying "The entry point method could not be loaded":

```
 $ mono Some-App.exe
 The entry point method could not be loaded
 $
```

How can I determine what caused the error? I.e. to get some more meaningful message like:

- The file XXX.dll is missing,
- This app uses feature YYY which is unavailable under Linux,
- There were an error ZZZ.